# Error correction : The vaccine when hit the Indian market is dogged by controversy

Tags: exam-questions

> The vaccine when hit the Indian market is dogged by controversy.

I am perplexed between two possible corrections of the above sentence.

> A) The vaccine which hit the Indian market is dogged by controversy.

Or

> B) The vaccine when hit the Indian market was dogged by controversy.

Please tell if both these corrections are correct?

Edit : I think sentence B is also wrong and can be further improved by adding *it* after *when* I.e.

> C) The vaccine when it hit the Indian market was dogged by controversy.

I think A and C are correct and B is wrong, Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correctness of A can be debatable depending on whether you believe the word "which" should be applied to nonrestrictive modifying clauses only. Hitting the Indian marking is essential information to identifying which vaccine we are talking about, so a restrictive modifying clause is necessary. Thus, "that" should be used instead of "which".

B is not correct as you have already noted.

C would be correct if you add commas before "when" and after "market" to create a relative clause.

So, acceptable corrections would be either:

1. The vaccine that hit the Indian market is dogged by controversy.
2. The vaccine, when it hit the Indian market, was dogged by controversy.

If you had to choose from the corrections you provided, A would be the most correct one.

Answer (score 1):

**which** is a relative that acts a proxy for an antecedent noun.

> The vaccine, <sup>*←*</sup> which hit the Indian market ...

**when** heads/introduces a temporal subordinate clause and has no nominal antecedent.  The temporal subordinate clause with finite verb needs a subject. We can use a pronoun for that purpose. The pronoun refers to another noun in its vicinity, most often to an antecedent noun.

> The vaccine, when **it** hit the Indian market ...

Here you can see that the subject in the temporal subordinate clause need not be the same as the subject in the matrix clause:

> The vaccine, when the company that made it went bankrupt, became unavailable.

Here's an example where the pronoun  refers to a noun that follows afterwards:

> When the company that made **it** went bankrupt, **the vaccine** became unavailable.